# Django Rest Framework - Attribute Error: 'function' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, api, heroku, django-rest-framework

everybody.

So I'm learning about django rest framework and how to deploy on Heroku. I'm having this issue in my app and I have no ideia how to solve it.

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.views import Response

from api import models, serializers
from api.integrations.github import GithubApi


@api_view(['GET'])
class LibrarynViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    queryset = models.Library.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.Library(queryset, many=True)
    lookup_field = "name"

    def retrieve(self, request, login=None):
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

routes.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from api import views

routers = DefaultRouter()
routers.register("organization", views.LibraryViewSet, basename="Library")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(routers.urls)),
]
```

Error:

```
extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

As I said, I'm learning so I have no ideia how to solve it.

I would appreciate if you help me. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `@api_view` it is not compatible with viewset for manage http methods which you want use you should use `http_method_names` attribute:

```
class LibrarynViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    http_method_names = ['get',]
```

Comment: Nikita, today you're my hero! Thank you so much.